# Facet field with reversed wildcard tokens

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I have a field defined as follows:

```
<fieldType name="textcleaning" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
                    pattern="^\p{Punct}*(.*?)\p{Punct}*$"
                    replacement="$1"/>
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
                    pattern="^\p{Punct}*(.*?)\p{Punct}*$"
                    replacement="$1"/>
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

I want to facet on this field, but I get both direct and reversed tokens in the answer:

```
"\u0001fo",90671,
"of",90671,
"\u0001detinu",82915,
"united",82915,
"\u0001grebmoolb",74461,
"bloomberg",74461,
```

Is there a way to filter the reversed tokens out of my facet results? I tried using facet.prefix, but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dedicated field that has the definition you want for your facets - i.e. create a similar field without the `ReversedWildcardFilterFactory` and use that for faceting instead. You can still search and filter against the field that you've already created.

Also, in general, you normally want to use a StrField for faceting as you'll get a facet for each token generated (as you can see here), but if your use case makes sense with a facet for each token in the value, this solution should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help! In my case it does make sense to facet for each token. I thought of "spliting" my field in two others: one with only the reversed tokens and one with the direct ones. This way I'll have less tokens in the end (less space required). The counterpart is that I'll need to check the query in my application to choose the appropriate field.